# Remove specific items from Xcode 8 recent opened menu

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I have some recent opened projects in Xcode 8.3 and I want to remove some specific projects from `recent opened` menu and keep the rest.

**I don't want to clear the whole recent opened Menu.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you been looking at some naughty workspaces?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/293647

Comment: thank you @Callam, i already checked that answer but it is not working for the 10.X  version of OSX.

Comment: Delete the project folder.